# Replace all spaces with dashes, but not accents characters - PHP

Tags: php

I want to replace spaces with dashes, however the code is also replacing the accents characters with dashes:

```
$username = preg_replace("![^a-Z0-9]+!i", "-", $username);
```

How do I leave the letters with accents not replaced by dashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only changing spaces, in your RegEx, try matching the spaces.

```
$username = preg_replace("![ ]+!i", "-", $username);
```

I would also recommend against unescaped `\` characters - they have a habit of meaning something in both PHP strings (more so with double quotes) and in RegEx.

Alternatively, `\w` will match any word character, and `\d` will match any number, so `![^\w\d]+!iu` will match anything that isn't alphanumeric.

```
$username = preg_replace('![^\\w\\d]+!iu', '-', $username);
```

Note, the `i` makes it case-insensitive, the `u` makes it unicode safe.

Example:

```
echo preg_replace('![^\\w\\d\\\\]+!iu', '-', 'this is a testé');
```

outputs `this-is-a-testé`

Comment: Could you be more specific? Perhaps an example?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but none seems to be working, the code I put "![^a-Z0-9\]+!i" seems to be closer to what I need, the only issue is with letters with accents, which are subsituted with dashes. Trying with yours there must be an error seems word is directly not appearing.

Comment: Sometimes with regular expressions, you'll seemingly get further from solution before you get there. Ideally, I could do with some examples, of what's happening and what's going wrong.

Comment: I guess so. So do you have any other suggestion so I can test and see if it works?

Comment: I edited the initial code there was the \ which actually shouldn't be there, if that helps

Comment: Added a unicode safe flag: it seems to work for me with that alone.